# Hello World Neural Network to understand basics

Tags: python, keras, neural-network, tensorflow2.0, tf.keras

I am trying to build a noob neural net using tensorflow that learns to solve the equation  `y = 2x - 1`
Training data -

```
xs = [0,1,2,3,4,5]
ys = [-1,1,3,5,7,9]

xs = np.array(xs, dtype=float)
ys = np.array(ys, dtype=float)
```

I am using 3 different models which changes only in the input_shape as below -

Model 1 works perfectly -

```
model1 = keras.models.Sequential()
model1.add(keras.layers.Dense(units=1, input_shape=[1]))
model1.compile(optimizer='sgd', loss='mean_squared_error')
```

Model 2 works perfectly as well -

```
model2 = keras.models.Sequential()
model2.add(keras.layers.Dense(units=1, input_shape=(1,)))
model2.compile(optimizer='sgd', loss='mean_squared_error')
```

Model 3 fails in model.fit()

```
model3 = keras.models.Sequential()
model3.add(keras.layers.Dense(units=1, input_shape=(None,1,)))
model3.compile(optimizer='sgd', loss='mean_squared_error')
```

Here is the error -

```
ValueError: in user code:

    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1284, in train_function  *
        return step_function(self, iterator)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1268, in step_function  **
        outputs = model.distribute_strategy.run(run_step, args=(data,))
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1249, in run_step  **
        outputs = model.train_step(data)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1050, in train_step
        y_pred = self(x, training=True)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/keras/utils/traceback_utils.py", line 70, in error_handler
        raise e.with_traceback(filtered_tb) from None
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/keras/engine/input_spec.py", line 253, in assert_input_compatibility
        raise ValueError(

    ValueError: Exception encountered when calling layer 'sequential_13' (type Sequential).
    
    Input 0 of layer "dense_13" is incompatible with the layer: expected min_ndim=2, found ndim=1. Full shape received: (None,)
    
    Call arguments received by layer 'sequential_13' (type Sequential):
      • inputs=tf.Tensor(shape=(None,), dtype=float32)
      • training=True
      • mask=None
```

Here is the rest of the code I am using to train and predict the model.

```
model.fit(xs, ys, epochs=20)
model.predict([10.0])
```

Why `model1` works, despite not using a `tuple`, and why `model3` fails despite specifying `optional batch_size` argument as `null`?

Comment: the first two models have 1d input_shape, but model 3 expects 2d, whereas `xs` is 1d.

Comment: I don't think TF cares if the input_shape is specified by a tuple or a list.

Comment: @Joe - thanks for your answers - 2 followups - 1) Isn't providing batch size optional? so giving it a None value should be okay and 2) Keras official docs state this for the input shape - `shape: A shape tuple (integers), not including the batch size. For instance, shape=(32,) indicates that the expected input will be batches of 32-dimensional vectors. Elements of this tuple can be None; 'None' elements represent dimensions where the shape is not known.` - you might be correct, but what am I missing here that input shape must be a tuple?

Comment: I don't know what the TF code does, but I expect that it just iterates over the input_shape, in which case giving it any iterable of valid values (e.g. integers, or None where allowed) would work. If they needed to store the input_shape in a set, or use it as a dictionary key, then they would need it to be hashable (not a list), in which case they'd either need to convert it or let the error get raised. But I suspect that the lack of an error is likely simply due to not doing anything to the input_shape that actually requires it to be a tuple.

Comment: I believe that the first value to `input_shape` is the batch size, which can be None if you don't want to specify it. However, when you put `input_shape=(None,1)` you are telling TF that your input will be 2D, with the 2nd dimension equal to 1. If you do that, you cannot pass an input that is only 1d, like `xs` is.

Comment: Related https://github.com/mrdbourke/tensorflow-deep-learning/discussions/278

Comment: The input shape does NOT contain the batch size, @Joe is misinforming people here.

Comment: Well@Dr.Snoopy, I said "I believe.." because I wasn't 100% confident, but I was going off of the docs that say, "Input shape -
N-D tensor with shape: (batch_size, ..., input_dim). The most common situation would be a 2D input with shape (batch_size, input_dim)."  Do you have any other source that you can share?

Comment: That section of the docs refers to the inputs to the layer, i.e. the `call` function, not the `input_shape` argument to the constructor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Model 1, you define the input shape as [1], which indicates that the input data should have one feature. This works perfectly for your problem because your input data xs is one-dimensional, with a single feature per data point. Model 2 is equivalent to Model 1. Here, you use a tuple (1,) to specify the input shape, but it means the same thing as [1].

*In Model 3*, you specify the input shape as (None, 1). The use of None in the input shape indicates that the model should accept input data with a variable batch size. However, the issue here is that you've used (None, 1) which suggests that each input should have a shape of (batch_size, 1) where batch_size is variable. This is not what you intend, as you want to use a single feature per input. Using (None, 1) is not the correct way to specify a single feature input shape.

Comment: That explains it all, thank you!! Just one clarification- in model1, keras internally converts the list [1] to tuple (1,) as it expects input_shape to be a tuple?

Comment: The input_shape=[1] is essentially equivalent to input_shape=(1,). Both specify that the model expects input data with a single feature.

This conversion to a tuple is a convenience provided by Keras to make it easier to specify input shapes while maintaining consistency in the way shapes are represented.